# Argument data type bigint is invalid for argument 1 of substring function

Tags: sql-server, casting

I have this code in SQL Server, but I got the mentioned error while running, the `NationalId` column is of `int` datatype.

what casting that should I use to pass this error because I think that `NationalId` needs to be casting

> Error: Argument data type bigint is invalid for argument 1 of substring function

Code:

```
SELECT
    c.NationalId,
    CAST (CASE
             WHEN LEFT(c.NationalId, 1) = 3 
                THEN 2000 + SUBSTRING(c.NationalId, 2, 2)
                ELSE 1900 + SUBSTRING(c.NationalId, 2, 2) 
          END + '-' + SUBSTRING(c.NationalId, 4, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(c.NationalId, 6, 2) AS Date) AS Birthday,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.NationalId
     , CAST (CASE
             WHEN LEFT(cast(c.NationalId as varchar(32)), 1)= 3 
                         THEN '20' + SUBSTRING(cast(c.NationalId as varchar(32)), 2, 2)
             ELSE '19' + SUBSTRING(cast(c.NationalId as varchar(32)), 2, 2) END 
                     + '-' + SUBSTRING(cast(c.NationalId as varchar(32)), 4, 2) 
                     + '-' + SUBSTRING(cast(c.NationalId as varchar(32)), 6, 2) AS date
                           ) AS Birthday
```